# Bash - Linux - Find a Match in a line and Print to the end of line SED / Awk / Grep

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I do a ps -ef command and I have few parameters that I pass on to the commands that are running. I want to print only the process name which comes after the hostname\process1. I cannot use awk command with -f to break up the line; it's not practical as ps command output differs. So perhaps there is a sed command I can use?

Example Input

```
/bin/ksh /var/tmp/xxx -bin -tin /tet/1/3/5/host1/bin/x1.sh
/bin/ksh /var/tmp/xyz -bin -tin /tet/1/3/5/host2/bin/y2.sh
/bin/ksh /var/tmp/ttt -bin -tin /tet/1/3/5/host3/bin/z3.sh
```

Output should look like this

```
host1 x1.sh
host1 y2.sh
host1 z3.sh
```

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F/ '{print $(NF-2), $NF}'
```

gives you your desired output.

Comment: Thx that did work - Some of the ps output differed from above - but the lines I wanted also showed. Can I ask u please to provide a bried description of the command?

Comment: when u have a moment please provide description of the command

Comment: All this does is set `/` as the field separator (`-F/`) then for each line, print the 3rd last and last fields (`NF` is the awk variable for number of fields for this line, and `$NF` is the **value** of the last field)

Answer (score 0):

**`sed`** alternative approach:

```
sed -E 's:.*/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)$:\1 \2:' file
```

The output:

```
host1 x1.sh
host2 y2.sh
host3 z3.sh
```